# Is there a way to automate ansible vault within the playbook

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, automation, ansible, ansible-vault

After automating pulling the secrets from AWS, I wanted to use Ansible Vault to lock it up, and so I first tested this manually. Is there a way to do this through ansible playbooks. We need to automate it so we don't have to constantly lock and unlock it when we pull a new secret.

Comment: I found that I could use a python script instead and use that python script within the playbook instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nifty [website](https://pypi.org/project/ansible-vault/1.0.4/) that is exactly what I need. It made use of my second route which was to use a python script to run the vault and place this within the playbook.